# Docker mongo auth SCRAM-SHA-1

Tags: mongodb, docker

System

> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
> Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
>  Release: 16.04

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=test1
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=test1
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    command: [--auth]
```

I try to access mongo:

```
mongo -u test1 -p'test1' --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase admin
```

and it give some error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
2019-01-06T17:06:39.987+0700 Error: 2 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "Auth mechanism not specified", code: 2, codeName: "BadValue" } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1287
exception: login failed
```

So I try with specific auth mechanism:

```
mongo -u test1 -p'test1' --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase admin --authenticationMechanism SCRAM-SHA-1
```

and it give some error too:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
2019-01-06T17:07:44.967+0700 Error: 2 SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism support not compiled into client library. at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1287
exception: login failed
```

I confused about error msg `SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism support not compiled into client library. at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1287`. How to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: have u found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your MongoDB shell is an old version (2.6.10) that does not support the SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism. More recent versions (as of writing the latest is 4.0.3) support it and have it activated by default.

You most probably installed the `mongodb` package from the official Ubuntu repos using `sudo apt install mongodb`. Follow the instructions from [the MongoDB documentation for installing on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) to install the official `mongodb-org` package.

**Make sure to first backup any data that may be affected by uninstalling the `mongodb` package.**

Don't forget to first uninstall the package you already installed, as indicated by the doc, with:

```sh
sudo apt remove mongodb
sudo apt purge mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below mentioned-section in the mongod.conf file (/etc/mongod.conf)

```
setParameter:
  authenticationMechanisms: PLAIN,SCRAM-SHA-256
  enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

Here we are setting the authentication mechanism as plain or SCRAM-SHA-256.
"enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false" will make sure that when connecting from localhost, do not bypass authentication.